# How to fly to a location in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

So I'm really new to react and leaflet but all I want to do is basically have the user enter some input, and after they press enter, trigger an event which then flies to the coordinates generated from that input. I am using geocode and the lat long coordinates are successfully generating. However I a not sure how to make the map fly to that location. Here is what I have so far:

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      position: [43.653225, -79.383186]
    }
  }
  mapRef = React.createRef();

  changePos (pos) {
    this.setState({position: pos});
    this.mapRef.current.flyTo(pos);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS = {false}>
        <div className = "App">
          <div id="title">
            <h1>
              CovidStopSpots
            </h1>
              <p>A responsive tracker for Covid-19.</p>
          <SearchBar changePos = {this.changePos.bind(this)}></SearchBar>
          </div>
          <div id="map">
            <MapContainer center={this.state.position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} ref={this.mapRef}>
              <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              />
              <Marker position={[43.653225, -79.383186]}>
                <Popup>
                  A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
            </MapContainer>
          </div>
      </div>
      </ChakraProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

also the current code is generating this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'flyTo' of null
```

Comment: why don't you use only set state part to change the position?
also read the position from the state in the Marker. you already hardcoded it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In react-leaflet version 3 you can take the map instance using `whenCreated` prop and then use it to fly to another location when you do not want to use it for a component that is `MapContainer's` child.

```
this.state = {
      position: [43.653225, -79.383186],
      map: null
 }
```

Remove ref and use `whenCreated` prop

```
<MapContainer center={this.state.position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} whenCreated={map => this.setState({ map })}>
```

and then on your changePos event use this.state.map to fly

```
 changePos (pos) {
    this.setState({position: pos});
    const {map} = this.state;
    if (map) map.flyTo(pos);
 }
```

Comment: thanks. I'm a little new to this what exactly does the code in the when created prop do? And also won't const {map} = this.state just set the constant map to this.state? Don't we have to do this.state.map?

Comment: `whenCreated` returns the map instance and then you assign it to a variable to be able to use it further. `const {map} = this.state` is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It is an es6 feature and can be used to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.