# React-Leaflet does not render Map on the entire state after update

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-state

My web-app, for some reason, isn't **fully** updating when the state changes.

Let me explain: I have a React-Leaflet Map that I wish to update anytime a user changes filtering criteria. For instance, changing the city where some `Markers` appear. For this purpose I've built a backend that loads some JSON from an endpoint, my web-app fetches it, and then successfully updates the *items* array where I store the data I need. After this, the new Markers are indeed added to the Map.

What **is not** updated is the `zoom` and the `center` of my `MapContainer`, despite the functions that take care of this are correctly executed when the component is mounted.

So, in short, inside `componentDidMount` I fetch data which is then passed to the `state` which is used to populate and render my Map. After that, if the user presses the *filter* button and inserts a new city my `componentDidUpdate` recognizes that `props` have changed, it then fetches new data. Still, my Map only re-renders adding the new Markers **without** setting the new zoom and the new center.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me on this one? Huge thanks in advance.

```js
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import MyMarker from "./MyMarker";
import "./MapObject.css";

/*
  IMPORTANT: We are NOT taking into consideration the earth's curvature in
             neither getCenter nor getZoom. This is only left as it is for
            the time being because it is not mission critical
*/

// Function to calculate center of the map based on latitudes and longitudes in the array
function getCenter(json) {
  // Array to store latitude and longitude
  var lats = [];
  var lngs = [];
  const arr = Object.keys(json).map((key) => [key, json[key]]);

  // Loop through the array to get latitude and longitude arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    lats.push(arr[i][1].Latitude);
    lngs.push(arr[i][1].Longitude);
  }
  const lat = lats.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / lats.length;
  const lng = lngs.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / lngs.length;
  return [lat, lng];
}

// Function to get the zoom level of the map based on the number of markers
function getZoom(json) {
  // Array to store latitude and longitude
  var lats = [];
  var lngs = [];
  const arr = Object.keys(json).map((key) => [key, json[key]]);

  // Loop through the array to get latitude and longitude arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    lats.push(arr[i][1].Latitude);
    lngs.push(arr[i][1].Longitude);
  }
  const zoom = Math.floor(Math.log2(lats.length)) + 8;
  return zoom;
}

export default class MapObject extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      map: null,
      dataIsLoaded: false,
      zoom: null,
      position: [null, null],
      items: [],
    };
  }

  changePos(pos) {
    this.setState({ position: pos });
    const { map } = this.state;
    if (map) map.flyTo(pos);
  }

  fetchData(filter, param) {
    fetch(`https://my-backend-123.herokuapp.com/api/v1/${filter}/${param}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((json) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            items: json,
            dataIsLoaded: true,
            zoom: getZoom(json),
            position: [getCenter(json)[0], getCenter(json)[1]],
          },
          () => {
            console.log("State: ", this.state);
            this.changePos(this.state.position);
          }
        );
      });
    console.log(
      "Fetched new data: " +
        "DataisLoaded: " +
        this.state.dataIsLoaded +
        " " +
        "Zoom: " +
        this.state.zoom +
        " " +
        "Lat: " +
        this.state.position[0] +
        " " +
        "Lng: " +
        this.state.position[1]
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData("city", this.props.filterValue);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.filterValue !== this.props.filterValue) {
      this.fetchData("city", this.props.filterValue);
      //MapContainer.setCenter([getCenter(this.state.items)[0], getCenter(this.state.items)[1]]);
    }
  }

  render() {
    // Logic to show skeleton loader while data is still loading from the server
    const { dataIsLoaded, items } = this.state;
    console.log("Rendering!");

    if (!dataIsLoaded)
      return (
        <div className="bg-white p-2 h-160 sm:p-4 rounded-2xl shadow-lg flex flex-col sm:flex-row gap-5 select-none">
          <div className="h-full sm:h-full sm:w-full rounded-xl bg-gray-200 animate-pulse"></div>
        </div>
      );

    // Logic to show map and markers if data is loaded
    return (
      <div>
        <MapContainer
          id="mapId"
          whenCreated={(map) => this.setState({ map })}
          attributionControl={true} // remove Leaflet attribution control
          center={this.state.position}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {this.state.map}
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <MyMarker
                name={item.Name}
                city={item.City}
                prov={item.Province}
                lat={item.Latitude}
                lng={item.Longitude}
                phone={item["Phone Number"]}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm leaving a GIF down below to showcase the current behavior. You can also briefly notice that the Markers "disappear": that's because the new Markers have been rendered taking into account the new filter, that's why I then proceed to manually zooming out to show that the new Markers have been indeed rendered.

[Demo of the bug](https://media.giphy.com/media/PYTiZ4HUXWk2K19eNi/giphy.gif)

**EDIT**: I am now trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66275459/4615278) solution, but I’ve been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: What version of react-leaflet do you use? Could you create a demo with mock data same with that coming from your backend?

Comment: Dear @kboul, thank you for your prompt response! I've solved the issue in a slightly different way, but the approach taken is roughly identical to that you've employed in your answer to the other question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrightie, I decided to fully refactor my code and to switch to a `function` component, from the `class` component I had earlier.

The solution I've implemented comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72908602/4615278).

The key was to add the following function to my code:

```js
/*
 Function to move the map to the center of the markers after the map
 is loaded with new data and with the correct zoom.
*/
function FlyMapTo(props) {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    map.flyTo(props.center, props.zoom);
  });

  return null;
}
```

After that, I add this component to the JSX that takes care of rendering the parent component (my `Map.js`):

```js
return (
  <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <MyMarker
          name={item.Name}
          city={item.City}
          prov={item.Province}
          lat={item.Latitude}
          lng={item.Longitude}
          phone={item["Phone Number"]}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
    <FlyMapTo center={center} zoom={zoom} />
  </MapContainer>
);
```

Just for reference, should anyone face a similar problem, I'm adding the full code of my new `Map.js` component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./MapObject.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import MyMarker from "./MyMarker";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";

/*
  IMPORTANT: We are NOT taking into consideration the earth's curvature in
             neither getCenter nor getZoom. This is only left as it is for
            the time being because it is not mission critical
*/

// Function to calculate center of the map based on latitudes and longitudes in the array
function getCenter(json) {
  // Array to store latitude and longitude
  var lats = [];
  var lngs = [];
  const arr = Object.keys(json).map((key) => [key, json[key]]);

  // Loop through the array to get latitude and longitude arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    lats.push(arr[i][1].Latitude);
    lngs.push(arr[i][1].Longitude);
  }
  const lat = lats.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / lats.length;
  const lng = lngs.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / lngs.length;
  return [lat, lng];
}

// Function to get the zoom level of the map based on the number of markers
function getZoom(json) {
  // Array to store latitude and longitude
  var lats = [];
  var lngs = [];
  const arr = Object.keys(json).map((key) => [key, json[key]]);

  // Loop through the array to get latitude and longitude arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    lats.push(arr[i][1].Latitude);
    lngs.push(arr[i][1].Longitude);
  }
  const zoom = Math.floor(Math.log2(lats.length)) + 8;
  return zoom;
}

// Function to move the map to the center of the markers after the map is loaded with new data
function FlyMapTo(props) {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    map.flyTo(props.center, props.zoom);
  });

  return null;
}

export default function Map(props) {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(null);
  const [center, setCenter] = useState([null, null]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [dataIsLoaded, setDataIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://my-backend-123.herokuapp.com/api/v1/${props.filterType}/${props.filterValue}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        if (json["detail"] === "Not Found") {
          setItems([]);
          setDataIsLoaded(false);
        } else {
          setItems(json);
          setDataIsLoaded(true);
          setCenter(getCenter(json));
          setZoom(getZoom(json));
        }
      });
  }, [props.filterType, props.filterValue]);

  // If data is not loaded, show an empty map
  if (!dataIsLoaded && items.length === 0) {
    return (
      <MapContainer
        center={{ lat: 45.0, lng: 12.0 }}
        zoom={5}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
    );
    // If data is loaded, show the map with markers
  } else if (dataIsLoaded) {
    return (
      <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <MyMarker
              name={item.Name}
              city={item.City}
              prov={item.Province}
              lat={item.Latitude}
              lng={item.Longitude}
              phone={item["Phone Number"]}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <FlyMapTo center={center} zoom={zoom} />
      </MapContainer>
    );
  }
}
```